# Choose-your-path book in which a spaceship breaks apart, forcing a kid to jettison onto a planet where he encounters aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, space, choose-your-own-adventure

I'm looking for a Choose-your-path book that starts with a research spaceship breaking apart, forcing a kid to jettison onto a planet that has breathable air. Some of the adventures cause him to encounter an alien creature the author calls a 'novepuss;' a land octopus-like creature with nine tentacles, one being used for human communication. Another adventure causes him to get willingly stuck in clinging fungus that produces laughing gas.

Anyone know what the book's title is?

Answer (score 7):

Likely to be [*Villains of Volturnus*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1332940). From one of the reviews:

> I made an escape and ran into a long-eyelashed novepus (nine-legged
> octopus type creature) herding some flightless birds.

Other aspects mentioned are an insectoid tutor called Jac, a 'compu-pal' called Ting, and the protagonist Kyiki.